# How I Declare a new empty Object in androidStudio

Tags: java, object, android-studio

I Created a class and named it "PaymentObject"

```
public class PaymentObject implements Serializable {

        double precentsValue;
 String PrecentsText;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return PrecentsText;
}




public PaymentObject(String paymenttext,double paymentvalue)
{
   this.PrecentsText=paymenttext;
this.precentsValue=paymentvalue;


}
public String getPrecentsText(){return PrecentsText;}
public void setPrecentsText(String percents){this.PrecentsText=percents;}
public double getPrecentsValue(){return precentsValue;}
public void setPrecentsValue(double percentsvalue) {this.precentsValue=percentsvalue;}


}
```

In my mainactivity class I want to initialize a new **empty** object of PaymentObject type
and then set values to the object .
 like this :

```
PaymentObject po = new PaymentObject();
    po.setPrecentsValue(1);
    po.setPrecentsText("100%");
```

but when I do  that there is an Error  "PaymentObject (string,double) in PaymentObject cannot be applied to ()"
(thas work only if I add the values when I declare on the new object )
but I want to open an **empty**  object and just then set the values  ...
what should I do?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To create empty objects just create a default constructor:

```
public PaymentObject(){}
```

When you don't declare default constructor (without parameters) - it's like you prohibit to create empty objects.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have an constructor which has no arguments. You have ti explicitly create one for that.

```
public PaymentObject(){
    //initialize maybe with default values if any based on use case
}
```

You may want to read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html).

Answer (score 1):

In your Code Listed, you have modified the default constructor behaviour to accept two arguments.

I would suggest, have 2 constructors one without the arguments and one with it.

Such that you can create an empty object when you need or an object with Initialized member varaibles.

modify the code like this:

```
public class PaymentObject implements Serializable {

        double precentsValue;
        String PrecentsText;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return PrecentsText;
}

public PaymentObject()
{

}

public PaymentObject(String paymenttext,double paymentvalue)
{
   this.PrecentsText=paymenttext;
   this.precentsValue=paymentvalue;

}

public String getPrecentsText(){return PrecentsText;}
public void setPrecentsText(String percents){this.PrecentsText=percents;}
public double getPrecentsValue(){return precentsValue;}
public void setPrecentsValue(double percentsvalue) {this.precentsValue=percentsvalue;}


}
```